# Fluent API Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I keep on getting this error message. How can I sort this out. I am also using fluent API.

Code as follows:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; 

        public ICollection<School> Schools{ get; set; }
    }
```

Fluent API config

```
  builder.ToTable("Person");
  builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
  builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

> {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table 'Person' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__122_0

Note: The solution should be in Fluent API.

Comment: Can you show us the code that throws the exception?

Comment: Fluent API are for model configuration and won't help in your case. There is something wrong with your `Person` or `School` updating code. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: It gets thrown on await _db.AddAsync(person);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();``

Comment: Make sure `person.Id` is `0` before calling `AddAsync`

Comment: You need to also share the code at the point the Exception occurs (include the creation of the model if that is not also located there)

Comment: @IvanStoev  The `person` record actually had an ID assigned to it. It works now Thanks.